Could a proper dependent claim of an allowed independent claim be rejected?
Independent claim:
X is a positive number;

there are three other numbers: A, B, and C;

Y happens if A <= X, B <= X, and C <= X;

Dependent claim:
C is restricted to always equal zero.
If C is restricted to always equal zero, then the condition C <= X is always true, which is equivalent to not having this condition to begin with.
The condition in the dependent claimed has been broadened. If we take this to the limit, we can also restrict A and B to be zeros as well. Hence, Y always happens. In this extreme scenario, the dependent claim would be either obvious, useless, or not novel, as Y always happens. But it would still technically be a proper dependent claim, correct?
So then, is it possible that a proper dependent claim is rejected despite its parent claim being allowed?

Your outline of an independent claim is not in a chain format at all. To make the question answerable please edit it to an actual claim.

This is probably a controversial subject and I don't think there is going to be any case law that elucidates this kind of issue but here is my humble take on it:
First of all, there are going to be differences in treatment for a machine vs a method. Here I'm discussing only the machine case.
If A, B, and C are specified to be "predetermined" in the parent claim, and a dependent claim where C is set to zero is found to be anticipated, the same prior art will anticipate the  parent claim as well. For the parent claim to be valid, one must have novelty and unobviousness for all values of A, B, and C, including the special case when C is zero. A well drafted claim should specifically exclude C==0 or other special cases that result in only obvious operation.
If A, B, and C are not "predetermined", then one is taking them as input. In this case there is no need to exclude C==0 in the parent claim and it is not possible to guarantee C==0 in the construction of the machine so the dependent claim does not make sense.

So then, is it possible that a proper dependent claim is rejected despite its parent claim being allowed?

It should not be possible on 102/103 grounds.

The answer to the question of the title is yes. A dependent claim may not have support in the specification, or be unclear as to its scope or not be a narrowing of its parent claim. It could also be objected to as not following proper form (more than a single sentence, for example).
